# Every connected part of my computer isnt working (and i dont know who to ask)

Tags: bios, flashing

Ive just patched (or whatever its called) a usb drive with a windows 10 iso using balenaEtcher. When I then booted into the usb (by setting the #1 boot priority to the usb) and suddenly, anything connected (so screens, mouse, keyboard, etc.) disconnected. And when I rebooted it, the issue was still there. The information about the model is in the attached image.

Ive also disconnected the usb drive to see if anything changed, but no it did not, and i honestly dont know, what forum i should ask